# System requirements for installing Ubuntu on my pc

Tags: system-installation

I have 2046 mb of DDR3 ram , an Intel core 2 duo E7500 processor  and Asus P5G41C-M LX mother boad can in this system Ubuntu 14.04 LTS can be installed error free and run  smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Can be installed, yes. But performance will vary according to your GPU too. Also ammount of the RAM you have won't allow you to run ubuntu with webbrowser/anything resource damding smoothly.
I would suggest running Xubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
512 MiB RAM (system memory)
5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media

Read the full info on requirement [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)